# vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone with tree-sitter and texlab

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, lsp, snippets, plugin-treesitter

`Vimtex` provides the very useful family of functions `vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()`, `vimtex#syntax#in_comment()` and `vimtex#env#is_inside('...')`, which come in handy for context sensitive snippets, e.g. with `LuaSnips`.

Is there a similar function exposed to `tree-sitter` + `texlab` that I can access in my snippet file? Or is there something similar in the Language Server Protocoll (LSP) I can use via `texlab`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the VimTeX dev; I'm sorry to say I can't answer the question directly. However, I can provide some relevant information that may or may not suffice as an answer. I should write it as a comment, but it is too long for that.

Treesitter is a method for parsing a specified format to e.g. provide syntax highlighting. If you use Treesitter for LaTeX, you (most likely) do not also use VimTeX syntax rules, since these are created with the standard regex-based Vim methods. I assume this is already well known, but it is an important thing to understand.

Further, LaTeX is a relatively hard language to parse, because the "same" syntax is used to distinguish between very different things. That is, you most likely do not just want a simple rule that matches any `\command{with}{args}`. First, any LaTeX command can have option groups `[...]`, and Beamer even adds the `<...>` option groups. The order of the various option and argument groups are important. And the only way to know the proper syntax for a specific command would be to fully parse the definition of that command. Or, alternatively, to specify the rules manually.

VimTeX does the former. That is, VimTeX provides a lot of guite general rules. But the real work has been to add a large amount of *specific* rules, e.g. to provide support for various common packages.

Why am I rambling about this? Well, the point is that Treesitter does not provide, as far as I know, anything near the amount of specific rules. Thus, even if you *did* make something like `vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone`, it would likely not work for every environment that starts a mathzone.

But: I *do* think it would be possible to create a Lua function that used the Treesitter API to make something similar. I welcome the effort and would be happy to learn how. In time, the Treesitter LaTeX parser may well become as good or better than VimTeX in every meaningful sense. But I do think it will take some more years for that to happen.

When it comes to `texlab`, I really don't have any valuable extra information. Sorry.